# How can I make a blurred or gradient photo frame?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to "frame" a photo with a rectangular blur or gradient.  Here is an example from the web that was ***not*** made using *Mathematica*.  (Of course, anything is possible; I suppose that this example from the web *may* have been made using *Mathematica*, but I'm guessing that it was not.)

*Regular* version:

[image: regular]

*Blurred* frame version:

[image: blurred]

***My question is, given a normal, unframed photo image, how can I accomplish this sort of blurred/gradient photo frame in Mathematica?***  Are there any relatively straightforward ways of accomplishing this sort of effect?  (The result doesn't have to be at all exactly like the example above; I'm just using the above example to illustrate generally what I would like.)  It would be preferable if it could be accomplished using *Mathematica* 8 or 9, but if *Mathematica* 10 is necessary, that is fine, too.

Suppose that I import the regular image in a variable `regular`:

```
regular = Import["regular.jpg"]
```

[image: regular]

I can blur the entire image using `Blur`:

```
Blur[regular]
```

[image: blurFull]

I can also introduce a temporarily solid frame (i.e., a solid band of white -- or, here, yellow, so that you can see it against this white page) using `ImagePad`:

```
solidFrame = ImagePad[regular, 10, Yellow]
```

[image: solidFrame]

Then I can blur the result with `Blur`:

```
Blur[solidFrame]
```

[image: blurredYellow]

Or, with a `White` `ImagePad`:

[image: blurredWhite2]

But, again, of course, the interior of the image becomes blurred as well.  So I need some way to delineate the "frame area" of the image from the "interior" of the image.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I don't think what you want is really a *blur* but a white frame with an alpha gradient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPxVj.png"]
```

### V11.2+

As of V11.2 it is directly supported by `ImageEffect`:

```
ImageEffect[pic, "FadedFrame"]
```

### Pre V11.2

```
alpha = Composition[
   GaussianFilter[#, 10] &,
   Image,
   BoxMatrix[#/2 - 5, #] &,
   Reverse
][
   ImageDimensions@pic
] 

SetAlphaChannel[pic, alpha]
```

> [image]

Comment: there is a superfluous comma inside `Composition` body. the code doesn't work in version 10 because of that comma. please correct it, as noone else can do it: "edit must be at least 6 characters"

Comment: @DanyloDubinin Thanks :) Deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The above is an excellent answer to the specific question posed.  Reading the documentation info on `ImageApply[]` and "Masking" provides another mechanism for performing image processing operations selectively on image regions.

Complex masks for `ImageApply[]` can be generated offline and `Imported` as mask images using software such as GIMP or Photoshop, giving some artistic freedom to the design of masks.